# "return arr" does not work inside if-statement of recursion function. Why?

Tags: javascript

This function finds into which the largest equilateral parts the field can be divided.

```
function field (width, height) {
  let big = Math.max(width, height);
  let small = Math.min(width, height);

  if (big / small === 1){
    let arr = [];
    arr.push(big);
    arr.push(small);
    return arr;
  }

  field(big-small, small);
}

field(1600, 500) // should be [100, 100]
```

It returns `undefined`, but if I use `console.log` before, it shows everything OK. Why?

Comment: if `big/small != 1` your function returns nothing (undefined).

Comment: Welcome to the stack overflow. You are getting undefined as you are not returning only when `big /small === 1` but in your case it won't happen. Just change this line `field(big-small, small);` with `return field(big-small, small);` and then the function will start work as it is suppose to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a return statement for the recursive call.

```
return field(big - small, small);
```

```js
function field(width, height) {
    let big = Math.max(width, height);
    let small = Math.min(width, height);

    if (big === small) { // easier check
        let arr = [];
        arr.push(big);
        arr.push(small);
        return arr;
    }
    return field(big - small, small);
}

console.log(field(1600, 500));
```